# How to solve a runtime error happening when I use a big size of static array

Tags: arrays, c, runtime-error

my development environment : visual studio

Now, I have to create a input file and print random numbers from 1 to 500000 without duplicating in the file. First, I considered that if I use a big size of local array, problems related to heap may happen. So, I tried to declare as a static array. Then, in main function, I put random numbers without overlapping in the array and wrote the numbers in input file accessing array elements. However, runtime errors(the continuous blinking of the cursor in the console window) continue to occur.

The source code is as follows.

```
#define SIZE 500000
int sort[500000];
int main()
{
    FILE* input = NULL;

    input = fopen("input.txt", "w");

    if (sort != NULL)
    {
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            sort[i] = (rand() % SIZE) + 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (sort[i] == sort[j])
                {
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            fprintf(input, "%d ", sort[i]);
        }
        fclose(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to reduce the array size from 1 to 5000, it has been implemented. So, Carefully, I think it's a memory out phenomenon. Finally, I'd appreciate it if you could comment on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried using `malloc`/`free`? The heap generally has far more memory than the stack.

Comment: The problem is that the last number has only a 1 in 500000 chance of being selected. So the code will take a very long time. A better approach is to fill the array with numbers from 1 to 500000 in order, and then [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) the array.

Comment: Another problem is that (on some systems) `rand()` only returns numbers from 0 to 32767. Try `printf("%d\n", RAND_MAX);` to see what the limit is on your system. If the limit is 32767, then you'll need to find a better random number generator, because your code won't work, and the Fisher-Yates shuffle won't work either.

Comment: @phuclv: `srand` is not inside the body of a loop. It is inside braces for `if` and `int main()`, neither of which is a loop.

Answer (score 1):

> “First, I considered that if I use a big size of local array, problems related to heap may happen.”

That does not make any sense. Automatic local objects generally come from the stack, not the heap. (Also, “heap” is the wrong word; a heap is a particular kind of data structure, but the `malloc` family of routines may use other data structures for managing memory. This can be referred to simply as dynamically allocated memory or allocated memory.)

> However, runtime errors(the continuous blinking of the cursor in the console window)…

Continuous blinking of the cursor is normal operation, not a run-time error. Perhaps you are trying to say your program continues executing without ever stopping.

> `#define SIZE 500000<br>`
> `...`
>             `sort[i] = (rand() % SIZE) + 1;`

The C standard only requires `rand` to generate numbers from 0 to 32767. Some implementations may provide more. However, if your implementation does not generate numbers up to 499,999, then it will never generate the numbers required to fill the array using this method.

Also, using `%` to reduce the `rand` result skews the distribution. For example, if we were reducing modulo 30,000, and `rand` generated numbers from 0 to 44,999, then `rand() % 30000` would generate the numbers from 0 to 14,999 each two times out of every 45,000 and the numbers from 15,000 to 29,999 each one time out of every 45,000.

> `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)`

So this algorithm attempts to find new numbers by rejecting those that duplicate previous numbers. When working on the last of *n* numbers, the average number of tries is *n*, if the selection of random numbers is uniform. When working on the second-to-last number, the average is *n*/2. When working on the third-to-last, the average is *n*/3. So the average number of tries for all the numbers is *n* + *n*/2 + *n*/3 + *n*/4 + *n*/5 + … 1.

For 5000 elements, this sum is around 45,472.5. For 500,000 elements, it is around 6,849,790. So your program will average around 150 times the number of tries with 500,000 elements than with 5,000. However, each try also takes longer: For the first try, you check against zero prior elements for duplicates. For the second, you check against one prior element. For try *n*, you check against *n*−1 elements. So, for the last of 500,000 elements, you check against 499,999 elements, and, on average, you have to repeat this 500,000 times. So the last try takes around 500,000•499,999 = 249,999,500,000 units of work.

Refining this estimate, for each selection *i*, a successful attempt that gets completely through the loop of checking requires checking against all *i*−1 prior numbers. An unsuccessful attempt will average going halfway through the prior numbers. So, for selection *i*, there is one successful check of *i*−1 numbers and, on average, *n*/(*n*+1−*i*) unsuccessful checks of an average of (*i*−1)/2 numbers.

For 5,000 numbers, the average number of checks will be around 107,455,347. For 500,000 numbers, the average will be around 1,649,951,055,183. Thus, your program with 500,000 numbers takes more than 15,000 times as long than with 5,000 numbers.

> When I tried to reduce the array size from 1 to 5000, it has been implemented.

I think you mean that with an array size of 5,000, the program completes execution in a short amount of time?

> So, Carefully, I think it's a memory out phenomenon.

No, there is no memory issue here. Modern general-purpose computer systems easily handle static arrays of 500,000 `int`.

> Finally, I'd appreciate it if you could comment on how to solve this problem.

Use a [Fischer-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle): Fill the array `A` with integers from 1 to `SIZE`. Set a counter, say `d` to the number of selections completed so far, initially zero. Then pick a random number `r` from 1 to `SIZE-d`. Move the number in that position of the array to the front by swapping `A[r]` with `A[d]`. Then increment `d`. Repeat until `d` reaches `SIZE-1`.

This will swap a random element of the initial array into `A[0]`, then a random element from those remaining into `A[1]`, then a random element from those remaining into `A[2]`, and so on. (We stop when `d` reaches `SIZE-1` rather than when it reaches `SIZE` because, once `d` reaches `SIZE-1`, there is only one more selection to make, but there is also only one number left, and it is already in the last position in the array.)